# How do you define functions in header files?

Tags: c, one-definition-rule, include-guards, program-structure

### The setup

If I have a program like this

A header file that declares my main library function, `primary()` and defines a short simple helper function, `helper()`.

```
/* primary_header.h */
#ifndef _PRIMARY_HEADER_H
#define _PRIMARY_HEADER_H

#include <stdio.h>

/* Forward declare the primary workhorse function */
void primary();

/* Also define a helper function */
void helper()
{
    printf("I'm a helper function and I helped!\n");
}
#endif /* _PRIMARY_HEADER_H */
```

---

The implementation file for my primary function that defines it.

```
/* primary_impl.c */
#include "primary_header.h"
#include <stdio.h>

/* Define the primary workhorse function */
void primary()
{
    /* do the main work */
    printf("I'm the primary function, I'm doin' work.\n");

    /* also get some help from the helper function */
    helper();
}
```

---

a `main()` file that tests the code by calling `primary()`

```
/* main.c */
#include "primary_header.h"

int main()
{
    /* just call the primary function */
    primary();
}
```

---

### The Problem

Using

```
gcc main.c primary_impl.c
```

does not link because the `primary_header.h` file gets included twice and therefore there is an illegal double definition of the function `helper()`. What is the correct way to structure the source code for this project such that double definitions do not happen?

Comment: Don't use macros and variables names that start with underscore `_`, they are reserved. So do `#ifndef PRIMARY_HEADER_H`, etc. Please post the error message of the compiler.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should only write your function's prototype in the header file, the body of your function should be written in a .c file.

Do this :

*primary_header.h*

```
/* primary_header.h */
#ifndef PRIMARY_HEADER_H
#define PRIMARY_HEADER_H

#include <stdio.h>

/* Forward declare the primary workhorse function */
void primary(void);

/* Also define a helper function */
void helper(void);

#endif /* PRIMARY_HEADER_H */
```

*primary_impl.c*

```
/* primary_impl.c */
#include "primary_header.h"
#include <stdio.h>

/* Define the primary workhorse function */
void primary()
{
    /* do the main work */
    printf("I'm the primary function, I'm doin' work.\n");

    /* also get some help from the helper function */
    helper();
}

void helper()
{
    printf("I'm a helper function and I helped!\n");
}
```

**Edit:** change `_PRIMARY_HEADER_H` to `PRIMARY_HEADER_H`. As @Jonathan Leffler and @Pablo said, underscore names are reserved identifiers

Comment: Note that there are no prototypes in the header.  There are function declarations, but the function declarations simply say that the functions take an indeterminate argument list (but not a variable argument list like `printf()` — such functions require an explicit prototype) and do not specify the prototype. You need to write `void primary(void);` in the header to provide a prototype. For symmetry, write `void primary(void) { … }` in the source file that defines the function too. Without a prototype, the compiler can't complain if you write `primary(13, 29.6, "arbalest");` as a function call.

Comment: Also observe the rules for reserved identifiers. [C11 §7.1.3 Reserved identifiers](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3) says, in part: • _All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use._ • _All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces._ Using `_PRIMARY_HEADER_H` for the header guard violates the first of those rules — don't do it despite the number of headers you see 'out there' that do the same.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for the precision, I might have mingled some words

Comment: @JonathanLeffler wow didn't know about the _Reserved identifers_, in school i've learnt to write `__FILE_NAME_H__`

Comment: People mimic what they see in system headers, not realizing that system headers _must_ use that notation to keep out of your way, just as you _must not_ use that notation to keep out of their way.  Sadly, it is common for tutors to be unaware of such minutiae — but they should be aware of them.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler i've edited the answer so people who see the answer will be aware now :)

Comment: What a radical statement about functions inside header files? What about `statinc inline` functions in header files? Header-only libraries?

Answer (score 10):

You almost never write a function inside a header file unless it is marked to always be inlined. Instead, you write the function in a `.c` file and copy the function's declaration (not definition) to the header file so it can be used elsewhere.

Comment: Bad statement about always inline. There can be `static inline` functions in header files.
See Linux kernel code, e.g. [include/linux/ip.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/ip.h)

Answer (score 2):

You can define a function in header files if it's [weak linkage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_symbol) like:

```c
// test.h
__attribute__((weak)) int test() {
    static int s = 0;
    return s++;
}

// a.c
#include "test.h"
#include <stdio.h>
void a(){
    print("%d", test());
}

// b.c
#include "test.h"
#include <stdio.h>
void b(){
    print("%d", test());
}

// main.c
#include "test.h"
#include <stdio.h>
void a();
void b();

void main(){
    a();
    b();
    print("%d", test());
}
```

`cc a.c b.c main.c` won't raise multiple definitions error and the output should be `012` as expected, meaning `a.c`, `b.c` and `main.c` share the same `test` function.
You can achieve the same result in c++ by using `inline`.

Moreover, weak linkage can also be used on variable definition, allowing you to define and initialize a global variable in header files without source files (similar to `inline static` in c++).

Note:

> Weak symbols are not mentioned by the C or C++ language standards.

So be careful when using it in c. But in c++, `inline` and `inline static` are portable form c++11 and c++17.