# invalid suffix "disassemble" on integer constant

Tags: c

I'm writing an Intel 8080 Disassembler when I came across this problem.

Here's the code:

```
int 8080disassemble(unsigned char *cbuffer, int pc){
    unsigned char* code=&cbuffer[pc];
    int opbytes=1;
    printf("%04x ",pc);
    switch(*code){
        case 0x00:printf("NOP");
            break;
        case 0x01:printf("LXI B,#$%02x%02x",code[2],code[1]);opbytes=3;
            break;
        case 0x02:printf("STAX B");
            break;
        case 0x03:printf("INX B");
            break;
        case 0x04:printf("INR B");
            break;
        case 0x05:printf("DCR B");
            break;
        case 0x06:printf("MVI B,#$%02x",code[1]);opbytes=2;
            break;
    }
}
```

It's a header file, that's why there is no includings.

Thanks!

I tried making it a pointer but didn't work

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to define functions in header files. See: [How do you define functions in header files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49099976/13843268).

Comment: Function names can't start with a digit. You could rename the following function to `disassemble8080`. Also, remember to post the error when asking for help :)

Comment: Identifier naming in C is typically introduced in the very first chapters of any beginner learning material...

Comment: Related: [Why can't variable names start with numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/342152/4284627) (that's tagged as C++, but it applies to C as well)

Answer (score 4):

Identifiers in C (such as functions and variable names) are not allowed to start with a digit.  The compiler is trying to parse `8080disassemble` as a number instead, and gets confused when it reaches the `d`.

Choose a different name for your function, such as perhaps `cpu_8080_disassemble` or `disassemble_8080`.

Comment: `i8080_disassemble()` :)

Comment: Thanks dude, I ended up renaming it to `dasm8080`.